# Infinite product made rigorous

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

I was reading a proof in Koblitz's book "p-adic numbers, p-adic analysis and zeta-functions" in page 22 that says:

For all real numbers $x$, the infinite product 
$$\pi x \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+\dfrac{x^2}{n^2} \right)$$
converges and equals $\sinh(\pi x)$.

Then, at some point the author states this (where $n=2k+1$):

$$\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{n\sin(\pi x/n)}=\prod_{r=1}^k \left( 1- \dfrac{\sin^2(\pi x/n)}{\sin^2(\pi r/n)} \right)$$

Now take the limit of both sides as $n = 2k + 1 \rightarrow \infty$. The left-hand side approaches $\sin(\pi x)/\pi x$. For $r$ small relative to $n$ the $r$th term in the product approaches $1-((\pi x/n)/(\pi r/n))^2 = 1 - (x^2/r^2)$. It then follows that the product converges to
$$\prod_{r=1}^\infty (1-(x^2/r^2))$$
Then it says that the rigorous justification of the previous statement is straightforward, and is left as an exercise.

The proposed exercise is proving that
$$\prod_{r=1}^k \dfrac {1- \frac{\sin^2(\pi x/(2k+1))}{\sin^2(\pi r/(2k+1))}}{1-\frac{x^2}{r^2}}$$
converges to $1$ as $k$ approaches infinity.

I know that, since the numerator of the fraction converges (to $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ as said before) showing this limit is $1$, proves that the denominator limit of products converges to the same value but I don't know how to rigurously prove this limit since it involves $k$ as the value por the upper limit in the product and it also appears in the factors.
Could someone explain how to prove this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Define

$$f_r(k) = \begin{cases} - \frac{\sin^2(\pi x/(2k+1))}{\sin^2(\pi r/(2k+1))}, &r \leqslant k\\ 0, &r > k \end{cases}$$

Using the inequality $2z/\pi \leqslant \sin z \leqslant z$, we can show that $|f_r(k)| \leqslant \frac{\pi^2x^2}{4r^2}$.  Hence, the series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty |f_r(k)|$ is uniformly convergent for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and, consequently the product $\prod_{r=1}^\infty (1 +f_r(k))$ is also uniformly convergent.

Thus, we can interchange limit and product to obtain

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^k \left[ 1 - \frac{\sin^2(\pi x/(2k+1))}{\sin^2(\pi r/(2k+1))}\right] = \lim_{k \to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^\infty (1 + f_r(k)) = \prod_{r=1}^\infty(1 + \lim_{k \to \infty}f_r(k))$$

Finally, we have

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} f_r(k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} -\frac{\sin^2(\pi x/(2k+1))}{\sin^2(\pi r/(2k+1))} =  \lim_{k \to \infty}- \frac{x^2}{r^2} \frac{\sin^2(\pi x/(2k+1))}{(\pi x/(2k+1))^2}\frac{(\pi r/(2k+1))^2}{\sin^2(\pi r/(2k+1))} \\ = - \frac{x^2}{r^2},$$

and, therefore,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^k \left( 1 - \frac{\sin^2(\pi x/(2k+1))}{\sin^2(\pi r/(2k+1))}\right) = \prod_{r=1}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{r^2} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I think I get almost everything but two steps.
Why do you define $f_r$ to be sero if $r>k$?
And, what do you do in the first equality after you prove the product converges uniformly?

Comment: @Eparoh. Because I'm applying a result about switching a limit with an infinite product which is justified when there is uniform convergence.  If $f_r(k) = 0$ for $r > k$ then your finite product with index up to $k$ is int eh form of an infinite product since terms beyond $r = k$ are $1$.  What I do after the first equality is switch limit and infinite product as I intended

Comment: Also to get the bound  $|f_r(k)| \leqslant \frac{\pi^2x^2}{4r^2}$ I need to bound the denominator using $\sin(\pi r/(2k+1)) \geqslant \frac{2}{\pi}(\pi r/(2k+1))$ which I can do if $\pi r/(2k+1) < \pi/2$ and this is true if $r < k$.  The inequality $\sin z \geqslant \frac{2z}{\pi}$ holds when $0 \leqslant z \leqslant \pi/2$.

Comment: Another way to look at this is we have a double sequence $S_{kl} =  \prod_{r=1}^l \left( 1 - \frac{\sin^2(\pi x/(2k+1))}{\sin^2(\pi r/(2k+1))}\right)$ and we want to evaluate $\lim_{k \to \infty} \lim_{l \to \infty} S_{kl}$ as $\lim_{k \to \infty} S_{kk}$.  If you know anything about double limits, then that is possible when the inner limit converges uniformly.

Comment: Thanks, know I get it. But, I don't know almost anythig about double limits of sequences, could you point some references where I could find the last result in your previous comment?